# Default website for unknown DNS names in Cpanel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel

I have a root domain and website at mydomain.com. I also have a subdomain called sub.mydomain.com which hosts a separate site. What I want is to have all URL requests redirected to sub.mydomain.com if the DNS name is anything other than mydomain.com (basically a catch all equivalent for DNS names)

At the moment if someone types anydomain.com it will always load the root website (mydomain.com); I don't want this, if someone types any other domain besides mydomain.com I want sub.mydomain.com's content to be displayed. Note I did not say redirect... The DNS name should still say anydomain.com and not rewrite the URL to point to sub.mydomain.com.

For reasons I'm not going to go into I cannot swap the sites around or use parked domains etc.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want redirection then how can you show content of subdoamin instead requested url. I hope below code will help you, It will redirect all websites to subdomain except your mydomain.com. Append it to .htaccess file:

> RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain.com
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]